How to create a shadow for a popup window in wxPython?
For example, like google drive. Google drive is developed using wxPython, which means there is such a possibility
Screenshot from Google Drive
Ideas using Bitmap and DC come to mind, but I would like a more beautiful solution.
I would like to get an idea on how to implement it

nothing in WxWidgets seems to do it, your best bet is using Win32 Api directly to set CS_DROPSHADOW on the main window class.

on some systems shadow is created by system and its theme - so it is not created by application.

There is no way to do it portably, but it's possible to do it at Win32 level, see this example for one possible implementation.
